# Turn Off Text Underlining in Sublime Text Emmet Package

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, emmet

I run Sublime Text 3 with Emmet package installed. Recently Sublime has started underlining my syntax while typing with no indication of why, similar to how spell check runs automatically. I've traced this "feature" to Emmet by adding it to my ignored packages, which removes the issue. Simple question then; How the hell do I turn off this "feature" of Emmet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s abbreviation capturing: https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-text-plugin#expanding-abbreviation
You can disable by setting `auto_mark` Emmet option to `false`.

But it’s better to describe cases where Emmet incorrectly marks abbreviations as errors in repo issues so I can fix it

Comment: Thank you, Sergey. The preview of the expanded abbreviation is very very useful, but the constant underlining of otherwise random words and letters is just a distraction when coding. Is there a way to turn off the syntax underlining function but keep the expanded abbreviation preview?

Comment: You can change `marker_scope` option Emmet preferences: you can set something like `"comment"` to make it less distracting or set to empty string to hide marker